# Setting MaximumRequestLength and RequestTimeout in ASP.NET Core 1.1.2

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1.2 in VS2017. Currently, I'm just running the server locally on a dev machine.

Lots of the documentation suggests that you can set MaximumRequestLength and RequestTimeout in web.config, but web.config has been removed from the template.

Should I just add my own? Or is there something I should do in the appsettings.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you hosting your ASP.NET Core application behind a local IIS? 
If so, I do believe IIS behavior is still driven by a web.config. For instance, I have mine configured to deal with request < 20 min specifying requestTimeout="00:20:00":

```
<aspNetCore
  requestTimeout="00:20:00"
  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
  arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
  forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="staging" /> <!-- value could be "development", "staging" or "production"-->
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's a bit hard to be sure when things from older documentation apply at the moment. The joys of new and rapidly changing frameworks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IIS you can add the web.config file to the project and update it with the required settings. Here's a link to the MS documentation on configuring an asp.net core app, with a blurb about the web.config at the very bottom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration.

Comment: Thanks very much. As you can see at the bottom of that reference:"If you are using Visual Studio and delete web.config, Visual Studio will create a new one." This isn't true, which confused me. Obviously some parts are out of date. Hard to be sure what. But thanks for your help. Between you and @Daboul I got it!